# Can a string be null or undefined in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Given is the following function prototype:

```js
function get(): string { /*.../* }
```

Can this function return `null` or `undefined`? Or only one of them? I try to understand which checks I should apply to check for validty of the return type of the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your `compilerOptions`. The `strictNullChecks` flag, to be precise.

**`strictNullChecks: false`**

```
function get(): string {
  return null; // ok
}

function get(): string {
  return undefined; // ok
}
```

In this scenario, you need extra checks against `null` and `undefined`.

**`strictNullChecks: true`**

The return value *must* be of type `string`. `null` and `undefined` are not allowed. No extra checks are necessary.

```
function get(): string {
  return null; // Compile-time error
}

function get(): string {
  return undefined; // Compile-time error
}
```

Check your `tsconfig.json` and set `compilerOptions.strictNullChecks` the way you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

No, This function must only return string.

If you want you have to set other type:

```
function get(): string | undefined | null {/*....*/ }
```

Or if you want to return only string you must check extra conditions.